# Nginx webdav is not showing files/folders with special chars

Tags: nginx, webdav

I have `Nginx` with `WebDAV` module working and everything is right, except the files or the folders that contains any square brackets `]` or `[`. That files/folder are never showed in the list.

I never had this problem with Apache, so I guess that Apache is doing some rewrite automatically. But now, I need to use nginx.

I just realize that it doesn't work either with the char `ª`. Clearly, it's an issue related to escape certain chars.

Using a web browser it works, but never with a WebDAV client (Cyberduck, Transmit, OSX Finder...)

This is my config file:

```
server {
    server_name my.server.com;

    root /home/web/dav;

    dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
    dav_ext_methods PROPFIND OPTIONS;

    auth_basic  "Description";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/passwd.dav;


    location / {
    autoindex on;

        client_body_temp_path /var/www/php5fpm/tmp/client-tmp 1 2;
        create_full_put_path on;
        client_max_body_size 50m;
        dav_access user:rw group:r  all:r;
    }
}
```

**Debug info:**

- Web Browser: http://drop.difun.de/Chrome.png
- WebDAV Client: http://drop.difun.de/Transmit.png
- Transcript: http://drop.difun.de/transcript.txt
- tcpdump for web browser and webdav client: http://drop.difun.de/tcpdump.txt
- Source code, from Chrome: http://paste.laravel.com/tXN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it was a bug. Solved and waiting to be merge to nginx-dav-ext, further information in  https://github.com/arut/nginx-dav-ext-module/issues/6